# Google Maps, hide mountain peak names

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

I'm working with the google maps api, but I'm having a hard time finding out which of the features I have to turn off to hide the annoying mountain peak names shown in the image:

[image]

Here's what I have:

```
var svmapstyle =[
        {
            "featureType":"administrative",
            "elementType":"all",
            "stylers":[
                {"visibility":"on"},
                {"saturation":-100},
                {"lightness":20}
            ]
        }, {
            "featureType":"road",
            "elementType":"all",
            "stylers":[
                {"visibility":"on"},
                {"saturation":-100},
                {"lightness":40}]
            }, {
                "featureType":"water",
                "elementType":"all",
                "stylers":[
                    {"visibility":"on"},
                    {"saturation":-10},
                    {"lightness":30}
                ]
            }, {
                "featureType":"landscape.man_made",
                "elementType":"all",
                "stylers":[
                    {"visibility":"simplified"},
                    {"saturation":-60},
                    {"lightness":10}
                ]
            }, {
                "featureType":"landscape.natural",
                "elementType":"all",
                "stylers":[
                    {"visibility":"simplified"},
                    {"saturation":-60},
                    {"lightness":60}
                ]
            }, {
                "featureType":"landscape.natural.landcover",
                "elementType":"label",
                "stylers":[
                    {"visibility":"off"},
                    {"saturation":-60},
                    {"lightness":60}
                ]
            }, {
                "featureType":"poi",
                "elementType":"all",
                "stylers":[
                    {"visibility":"off"},
                    {"saturation":-100},
                    {"lightness":60}
                ]
            }, {
                "featureType":"transit",
                "elementType":"all",
                "stylers":[
                    {"visibility":"off"},
                    {"saturation":-100},
                    {"lightness":60}
                ]
            }
        ];
```

Here's the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question because it might help someone else in the future.
What ended up working is this:

```
{
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
        {"visibility": "off"}
    ]
}
```